# Can I prevent zsh slowing with a large history?

Tags: zsh, command-history

I've just migrated from `bash` to `zsh`. I converted `~/.bash_history` for use in `zsh`. It's 150 000 lines long. `bash` is almost instantaneous to start up, but `zsh` is now fairly slow, taking half a second to start, and half a second to log out. I open and close sessions like crazy, so this adds up to a bit. If I remove `~/.zsh_history`, then it's near instantaneous again.

Is it possible to optimise `zsh` for a large history, or should I cull my history file?

Comment: You should cull your history file. HISTSIZE and SAVEHIST should be set to some reasonable size. I use 10,000 and that is large. 150,000 is huge.

Comment: @bdowning This might have to be the answer. However, this size history causes no noticeable slowdown in `bash`, so I was wondering if there were some option in `zsh` that I could disable, rather than limiting the history size. In fact, there is a setting in `bash` to save unlimited history, whereas AFAIK this is not available in `zsh`, so perhaps this is one area where it is not so streamlined.

Comment: This slowness is a bug, and has a recent patch: https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00218.html

Comment: @bukzor I tried compiling a version including this patch (and strace confirms no more `lseek`), but the actual startup isn't any faster. Only removing the history makes the startup fast again.

Comment: @lw1.at In the link I gave they show the first two lines of `strace -c` as evidence of the problem and the solution. Your problem might be actionable if you do the same. Also, reading more closely there was a revised version of that patch: https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00221.html

Comment: @bukzor I forgot to update this question. `zsh` is now almost instantaneous, so an update must have fixed it. (I'm now at 360 000 entries in my history, and it's all fine.) If you create an answer saying that it's a bug that has been fixed, I'll upvote and accept.